# MS Access VBA - Variables are not showing correct

Tags: ms-access, vba

Goodmorning,

I'm working in MS Access VBA to generate a automated email.
But to get what I want I need some values from the database.

```
Table: KlantInfo
KlantID: (AutoNumber)
Voorletters: (Text)
Voorvoegsel: (Text)
Achternaam: (Text)
```

I'm retrieving the information by a Query that is dependent from a ID from a form

```
Result Query:
ID = 1
Voorletters = A.B.
Voorvoegsel = van
Achternaam = Voorbeeld
```

When I got the return  im doing the following in VBA.

```
Code:
varVoor = rs!Voorletters
varMidden = rs!Voorvoegsel
varEind = rs!Achternaam

varNaam = varVoor & " " & varMidden & " " & varEind

MsgBox varNaam
```

Ive suspected this outcome: ***A.B. van Voorbeeld***
However this is the outcome im getting:

```
A.B. 
van Voorbeeld.
```

That outcome is also going to the mail.

At first I thought the problem was the dot after B. but that aint it, cause ive used the replace function to replace the dot with a space but still the same outcome.

Do you got any tips or advise?

Kind regards,
Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is the root cause but I think you could try the following:

```
varNaam = Replace(Replace(varVoor & " " & varMidden & " " & varEind, Chr(13), ""), Chr(10), "")
```